# How to Maven-ise an ActionBarSherlock project?

Tags: android, maven, jenkins

I have a Java Android project that builds fine in IntelliJ, but I want to have it build on a CI server running Jenkins (at Cloudbees). Rather than mess about with ant, it seemed sensible to use maven, to handle the ABS dependency. I created a simple pom to declare the dependency:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>com.myapp</groupId>
    <artifactId>android</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
  </parent>
  <groupId>com.myapp</groupId>
  <artifactId>myapp</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>myapp</name>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>

  <properties>
    <android.version>4.2.1_r1</android.version>
    <android.sdk.platform>17</android.sdk.platform>
    <google.android.maps.version>17</google.android.maps.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.actionbarsherlock</groupId>
      <artifactId>actionbarsherlock</artifactId>
      <version>4.1.0</version>
      <type>apklib</type>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

</project>
```

When I run it on my local machine, I get this:

```
[ERROR]   The project com.myapp:myapp:1.0.1-SNAPSHOT (C:\...\myapp\pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM: Failure to find com.myapp:android:pom: 1.0.0 in http://repo1.maven.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 4, column 11 -> [Help 2]
```

I've no idea what that means. Can anyone help me understand why it's failing, what this error means? If you have any tips on mavenising an ActionBarSherlock Android app to get it working on Jenkins/cloudbees I'd be most appreciative.

Comment: The error you got has nothing to do with mavenising ActionBarSherlock. Did you checkout the whole projects include the parent and run `mvn whatever` in the parent directory?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to use the [ivy plugin](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/) to integrate Maven with an ANT build.

The following task will pull down the "actionbarsherlock-4.2.0.apklib" file and add it (and it's dependencies) onto the ANT path "compile.path":

```
<ivy:cachepath pathid="compile.path">
    <dependency org="com.actionbarsherlock" name="actionbarsherlock" rev="4.2.0" conf="default"/>
</ivy:cachepath>
```

The reason why your Maven dependency doesn't work might be because the Maven module is using a packaging type of "apklib". This means the following might work instead:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.actionbarsherlock</groupId>
  <artifactId>actionbarsherlock</artifactId>
  <version>4.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

For more information see:

- [Android Ivy ActionBarSherlock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13699793/android-ivy-actionbarsherlock/13710965#13710965)
- [actionbarsherlock module in Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.actionbarsherlock%7Cactionbarsherlock%7C4.2.0%7Capklib)

Comment: Think I'll admit defeat and go back to trying to get it working with ant, as I can't get a maven build to work locally, and bringing ivy into it is likely to confuse more. Sadly I don't have the time to spend on learning everything about maven, and it's a pretty horrendous tool to learn. I've read the official reference guide and I still don't understand how to set up a simple project. roll on Gradle for Android, hopefully it will be better.